# Disqus style plugin for contact forms

Tags: contact-page

I've been using a combination of Swifmailer and jQuery to add a website contact form to sites that aren't using a cms, but the ease of implementing a Disqus module for  comments makes me wonder if an equivalent is available for a contact form? I've looked high and low on the Web, and I still haven't anything that can be used outside of WordPress, Drupal etc or doesn't require heavy configuration on the back end

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something like [Wufoo](http://www.wufoo.com/) forms or its [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/wufoo/). Design the form, get embed code, deploy.  Rinse and repeat.